# The assignment in streams (java)

Tags: java, api

Can I get streams API from this ?

```
public String getTheMostExpensiveIngredient() { 
    double help = 0.0; 
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();     
    for(Map.Entry<Ingredient, Double> x : list.entrySet()) { 
        if((x.getKey().getPrice() * x.getValue() > help )) { 
            help = x.getKey().getPrice() * x.getValue();        
            result.add(x.getKey().getName()); 
        } 
    } 
    return result.get(result.size()-1); 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to write this code using Java 8 [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/)?

Comment: Yes, please :) This is my first question on this website, so sorry for mistakes.

Comment: Can we get a more complete code snippet? At least include a wrapping method along with some context.

Comment: I don't think using Stream is a good idea here since you're relying on a external, mutable variable `help`.

Comment: I'm also a bit confused about why you have a `Map` called `list`. We definitely need some more code to know how to improve this,

Comment: `public String getTheMostExpensiveIngredient() {
         double help = 0.0;
         List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
         
        for(Map.Entry<Ingredient, Double> x : list.entrySet()) {     
                if((x.getKey().getPrice() * x.getValue() > help )) {
                        help = x.getKey().getPrice() * x.getValue();
                        result.add(x.getKey().getName());   
                }    
        }
        return result.get(result.size()-1);
    }`

Comment: I dont know how to edit in comment this code.

Comment: But i solve this problem. I add assigment `help` into `list` and in `if` i compare with the last item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are, as far as I can see, just looking for the name of the max element.  You don't modify any state. Or you don't have to. With streams you could do

```
String getTheMostExpensiveIngredient(Map<Ingredient, Double> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<Ingredient, Double>>
            .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(
                    e -> e.getValue() * e.getKey().getPrice())) // Optional<Map.Entry<..>>
            .map(e -> e.getKey().getName()) // Optional<String>
            .orElse(null);                  // just String
}
```

- First this turns the map you have into a stream of it's entries.
- Then it uses the `Stream.max` method to get the max entry.
- And finally it extracts the name from the entry and turns it into a raw String.

The "tricky" part is to tell the stream api how you define the maximum. It expects a `Comparator` for Map entries. This is handled by the `Comparator.comparingDouble(value * price function)`. It maps each entry to some value so it can be compared.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys :)  Stream.max never know about this function.